# Free WPF real time chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I am looking for some simple line chart solution. I need that for my app written in wpf that is part of a final college exam. I was trying to find some, but I have found only paid solutions and because I need that just for this purpose I dont want to pay for it.

The only additional requirement is that it must work with real time data, min 1 update per sec (brain affective data which im obtaining from neuroheadset).

Comment: I had the same problem so I made this https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

Comment: SciChart WPF has a free, fully featured edition for students and universities who need realtime charts. More info here: https://www.scichart.com/educational-discount-programme/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try [OxyPlot](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/). It's free, certainly fast enough for what you want, and fairly easy to use.

Comment: I tried it It looks nice, but has no real time update, a show stopper!

Comment: Oxy plot is a good option, but it did not filled my needs, so I made this https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

Comment: In my own experience, I found LiveCharts to be more MVVM-friendly than OxyPlot (in the latest version, you apparently can't use dynamic resources). LiveCharts also seems to support more graph types and overall looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

WPF Toolkit has a nice free easy to use chart control available [here.](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)

And [here's a good demo project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co) on codeproject.